# Transfer certificate from Windows to iMac for Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I recently got an iMac. Before that I created an IOS Developer account, paid for it, and created the .p12 and other things on my Windows computer.

I have got the .p12 file, I've moved it to key chain and exported it to a .cer file.

My problem is that I can't create an app with it. It comes up saying

> not a valid or untrusted license.

I've looked on the help and support section on IOS Developers Portal and places like that, but it won't install on my iPod.

If anyone has any suggestions which can help me then that would be great.

Comment: Can you tell us what the exact error is, and also how you actually created the certificate? The instructions are very clear at the provisioning portal, and are very specific for OS X, so I'm not sure how you did this in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the Windows machine plays into things here, and I'm a bit skeptical that you had a proper certificate and key pair. The simplest solution is to go to the developer portal and revoke any existing certificate. Then follow the usual process to request a new certificate (i.e. create a certificate signing request in Keychain, upload to the portal, wait a moment, download the certificate). This shouldn't create any hardship if you're just getting started.